# How can I zip filenames, images and predictions of a tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have the following code to predict image classes from files in a directory structure

```
import tensorflow as tf
image_dir = "images"
model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights="imagenet")
images = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(image_dir, labels=None, image_size=(224, 224), crop_to_aspect_ratio=True)
probs = model.predict(images)
preds = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.decode_predictions(probs, top=1)
```

Now I want to plot the images with their filenames and predictions, which is a bit complicated due to the batches.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cols = 6
box_size = 3
rows = (len(images.file_paths) + cols - 1) // cols
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(box_size * cols, box_size * rows))
metas = zip(axes.flatten(), images.file_paths, preds)
for image_batch in images:
    for img in image_batch:
        ax, file, pred = next(metas)
        name = file.split('/')[-1]
        ax.imshow(img / 255.0)
        ax.set_axis_off()
        ax.set_title(f"{name}: {pred[0][1]} {round(pred[0][2]*100)}%")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I get the expected grid of images with filename, class and percentage. But the images and predictions are all mixed up. How can I preserve the correlation?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add shuffle=False to image_dataset_from_directory()

see Note in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files